# .NET Core 6 - How to pass data on click

Tags: asp.net-core, onclick, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have a foreach loop that iterates through a Model and displays the data in a table. I want to pass the id (or any data from the model) to an element outside the foreach loop whenever I click on a button that corresponds to an entry in the loop, how can I do so?

Example:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var incident in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@incident.Title</th>
            <td>@incident.CustomerId</td>
            <td>@incident.ProductId</td>
            <td>@incident.DateOpened</td>
            @{
                var id = @incident.IncidentId;
            }
            <td><a asp-controller="Incident" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@incident.IncidentId" ><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a></td>
            <td >
                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can hover:cursor-pointer" > <<-- When clicked, store the model id, modelId = @incident.IncidentId
                </i>
           </td>
       </tr>
    }         
</tbody>

//Now I should have access to the exact variable (id) and pass it to other elements
```

Comment: you'll have to use javascript

Comment: @DanielA.White thats ok, i have this small library called alpinejs installed, but how would i go about it in plain js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with Javascript.

**Concept**

1. Label the delete button with the class `delete`.
2. Use `data-*` attribute to store the id value.
3. Create `click` event listener for all elements with (class) `.delete`.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var incident in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@incident.Title</th>
            <td>@incident.CustomerId</td>
            <td>@incident.ProductId</td>
            <td>@incident.DateOpened</td>
            @{
                var id = @incident.IncidentId;
            }
            <td><a asp-controller="Incident" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@incident.IncidentId" ><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a></td>
            <td>
                <i class="delete fa-solid fa-trash-can hover:cursor-pointer" data-id="@incident.IncidentId">
                </i>
           </td>
       </tr>
    }         
</tbody>

<div>
  <label>Selected Id:</label>
  <span id="selectedId"></span>
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
        deleteBtns.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', getSelectedId);
        });
    })();

    function getSelectedId() {
        var id = this.getAttribute("data-id");

        document.getElementById("selectedId").innerHTML = id;
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        var deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
        deleteBtns.forEach(btn => {
            btn.removeEventListener('click', getSelectedId);
        });
    }
</script>
```

[Sample .JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cejyrm4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var incident in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>incident.Title</th>
            <td>incident.CustomerId</td>
            <td>incident.ProductId</td>
            <td>incident.DateOpened</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Incident", new {  id = @incident.IncidentId })'" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```